# Error in WPSCAN ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, compiler-errors

I am triad to use wpscan. please help me. please. It show flowing error.

> ruby wpscan.rb www.security-ray.com [ERROR] Install missing ruby gem.
>   Please see README file or http://code.google.com/p/wpscan/
>
> ## root@hacker-desktop:/home/hacker/pentest/wpscan

I am using Ubuntu 11.04. And last version of wpscan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message couldn't be clearer. From the [README](http://code.google.com/p/wpscan/wiki/README):

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libopenssl-ruby
sudo gem install typhoeus xml-simple
```